# RealTime Pitch Shifting using TarsosDSP on Android

Tags: android, pitch-shifting, tarsosdsp

Here is what I want : 
1. Real time pitch shift while playing song.
2. Pitch shift should also be recorded to a file.

code :

```
    double rate = 1.0;
    RateTransposer rateTransposer;
    AudioDispatcher dispatcher;
    WaveformSimilarityBasedOverlapAdd wsola;

    dispatcher = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromPipe(mAudiopath, 44100, 5000, 2500);
    rateTransposer = new RateTransposer(rate);
    wsola = new WaveformSimilarityBasedOverlapAdd(WaveformSimilarityBasedOverlapAdd.Parameters.musicDefaults(rate, 44100));
    WaveformWriter writer = new WaveformWriter((TarsosDSPAudioFormat) dispatcher.getFormat(), BASE_PATH + "Recorded" + File.separator + "PITCHED_" + mVideoFileName + ".mp3");

    wsola.setDispatcher(dispatcher);
    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(wsola);
    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(rateTransposer);
    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(new AndroidAudioPlayer(dispatcher.getFormat()));
    dispatcher.setZeroPadFirstBuffer(true);
    dispatcher.setZeroPadLastBuffer(true);
    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(writer);
```

But here I am facing following error :

```
Error:(362, 41) error: cannot access AudioFormat
class file for javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat not found
```

for line

```
   WaveformWriter writer = new WaveformWriter((TarsosDSPAudioFormat) dispatcher.getFormat(), BASE_PATH + "Recorded" + File.separator + "PITCHED_" + mVideoFileName + ".mp3");
```

If I remove this line everything works fine only song is not recorded to file.
Please let me know if someone could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue was resolved using WriterProcessor class which has no dependency on JVM.

## ref : https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP/issues/64